# Does liquibase give access to java.sql.Connection for custom tasks

Tags: liquibase

Is there a way of having liquibase call a custom Java class/plugin and giving that class access to the underlying connection to make data changes.  I had a look but it only

So of our update steps require extensive data manipulation which is far far easier to do and debug in code than using SQL.  So I would want to write tasks that can extract, transform and save data.  Is that possible within the liquibase framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a subclass of Change using the extension framework (liquibase.org/extensions) the generateStatements() method is passed the Database object the change is being executed against. Calling

```
((JdbcConnection) Database.getConnection()).getUnderlyingConnection()
```

will return the java.sql.Connection used.

If you are using the CustomTaskChange interface, the execute() method that is executed is passed the same Database object you can get the connection from.